how to calculate mean of positive elements with cvxpy
I want to calculate the mean of positive elements as a constraint
like mean of （3，5，-1） is 4
I tried
x = cp.variable（3）
constraints = [ cp.mean(cp.pos(x)) 《 3 ]

but it contains zero，how to exclude zero elements,maybe
use Boolean variable

Add constraints on the x variables

You can make a MIP model to detect the positive elements with a binary variable, then count their sum A and their number B and the rest depends on your model. If you want to bound the average by a constant C then C*B<=A or C*B>=A will do it, but if C is also to be a variable in your model then you will not be able to write it as it is nonconvex even after relaxation.

Here's an implementation that builds out the comment from Michal Adamaszek.
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
x = cp.Variable(3)
y = cp.Variable(3, boolean=True)
M = 1000 # big M - a number that is larger than any possible value of x
c = 3 # average of positive x is at most c
cons = [cp.pos(x) <= M*y, # y_i can only be zero if x_i is non-positive
        cp.neg(x) <= M*(1-y), # y_i can only be one if x_i is non-negative
        cp.sum(cp.pos(x)) <= c*cp.sum(y), # average of positive x is at most c
        x <= 30, x >= -30] # bounds on x for purposes of example
t = [-1, 0, 1] # objective function coefficients for purposes of example
obj = cp.Maximize(t @ x)
prob = cp.Problem(obj, cons)
prob.solve()
print("status:", prob.status)
print("optimal value", prob.value)
print("optimal x", x.value)
print("optimal y", y.value)

Output:
status: optimal
optimal value 36.0
optimal x [-30.   0.   6.]
optimal y [0. 1. 1.]

Note that the elements of x that are equal to zero contribute toward the mean. You could add a small offset if you wanted to exclude them, but (in this example) you would just end up with small positive values equal to the offset.
